# Typescript "this" inside a class method

Tags: jquery, this, typescript, proxy-classes

I know this is probably painfully basic, but i am having a tough time wrapping my head around it.

```
class Main
{
     constructor()
     {
         requestAnimationFrame(this.update);  //fine    
     }

     update(): void
     {
         requestAnimationFrame(this.update);  //error, because this is window
     }

}
```

It appears to be the case that I need a proxy, so lets say using Jquery

```
class Main
{
     constructor()
     {
         this.updateProxy = $.proxy(this.update, this);
         requestAnimationFrame(this.updateProxy);  //fine    
     }

     updateProxy: () => void
     update(): void
     {
         requestAnimationFrame(this.updateProxy);  //fine
     }

}
```

But coming from an Actionscript 3 background, I am not really sure what is happening here. Sorry I am not sure where Javascript begins and TypeScript ends.

```
updateProxy: () => void
```

And also, I am not convinced I am doing this right. The last thing I want is most of my class having a a() function which needs to be accessed with `aProxy()` as I feel I am writing the same thing twice? Is it normal?

Comment: I found this documentation very helpful https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you want `this` captured the TypeScript way of doing this is via arrow functions. To quote Anders:

> The `this` in arrow functions is lexically scoped

Here is the way I like to use this to my advantage:

```
class test{
    // Use arrow functions
    func1=(arg:string)=>{
            return arg+" yeah" + this.prop;
    }
    func2=(arg:number)=>{
            return arg+10 + this.prop;
    }       

    // some property on this
    prop = 10;      
}
```

[View this in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20test%7B%0A%09%2F%2F%20Use%20arrow%20functions%0A%09func1%3D(arg%3Astring)%3D%3E%7B%0A%09%09%09return%20arg%2B%22%20yeah%22%20%2B%20this.prop%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09func2%3D(arg%3Anumber)%3D%3E%7B%0A%09%09%09return%20arg%2B10%20%2B%20this.prop%3B%0A%09%7D%09%09%0A%09%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20some%20property%20on%20this%0A%09prop%20%3D%2010%3B%0A%7D)

You can see that in the generated JavaScript `this` is captured *outside* the function call:

```
var _this = this;
this.prop = 10;
this.func1 = function (arg) {
    return arg + " yeah" + _this.prop;
};
```

so the `this` value inside the function call (which could be `window`) would not be used.

To learn more: [“Understanding `this` in TypeScript” (4:05) – YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1)

Comment: This is not necessary. What you're suggesting is idiomatic JavaScript, but TypeScript makes this unnecessary.

Comment: @TatianaRacheva using arrow functions in the context of class members was not allowed before TS 0.9.1 (and this answer was before that). Updated answer to new syntax :)

Comment: thanks for editing, since the answer is chosen by the OP, I was confused by it.

Comment: YOU MUST WATCH THE VIDEO - VERY USEFUL. ONLY 5 MINUTES

Comment: Thank you, @basarat. Light-bulb went on for context for *this* as soon as I saw you use the arrow function half-way through your video. I appreciate you.

Comment: I was bashing my head, and i was aware of context problems, but not this use of arrow functions, thanks!

Comment: @basarat Nice one Bas! I can't believe that I'd forgotten this and that I've circled back around to this 6 years later to find your answer again. I owe you a handroll  ;-)

Comment: I'm reviewing the linked generated script, and it no longer generates a `var _this = this;`, why is that?

Comment: @AaronLS on TypeScript playground to generate `var _this = this;` you have to choose `ES5`; since ES2015 - inside functions - `this` is used in place of `_this`

Answer (score 24):

If you write your methods like this, 'this' will be treated the way you expect.

```
class Main
{
    constructor()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());
    }

    update(): void
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());
    }
}
```

Another option would be to bind 'this' to the function call:

```
class Main
{
    constructor()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }

    update(): void
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience the update function is better defined like this:   update = () => { ... }

Comment: I've been using typescript a lot and have changed back and forth many times. at the moment, i only include the curly braces if it's more than a simple method call. also when using typescript + linq (which is godly), the format is nicer. example: Enumerable.From(arr).Where(o => o.id == 123);

Comment: I think if you look at the javascript which is generated, you will see a significant difference.  It is not a matter of taste.   update = () => {} will create lexical scoping via "var _this = this" compilation, your syntax will not.

Comment: You might need to upgrade your TypeScript library because it absolutely does include the "_this" context. Using "() => code()" or () => { return code(); }" will output 100% identical javascript code. Here's the output: http://i.imgur.com/I5J12GE.png. You can also see for yourself by pasting the code into http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: apparently bind(this) can be bad because it looses type safety on the original function args

Answer (score 9):

Very late to the party, but I think it is very important for future visitors of this question to consider the following:

The other answers, including the accepted one, miss a crucial point:

```js
myFunction() { ... }
```

and

```js
myFunction = () => { ... }
```

are **not** the same thing "with the exception that the latter captures `this`".

The first syntax creates a method on the prototype, while the second syntax creates a property on the object whos value is a function (that also happens to capture `this`). You can see this clearly in the transpiled JavaScript.

To be complete:

```js
myFunction = function() { ... }
```

would be the same als the second syntax, but without the capturing.

So, using the arrow syntax *in most cases* will fix your problem of binding to the object, but it's not the same and there are many situations where you do want to have a proper function on the prototype in stead of a property.

In these cases using a proxy or `.bind()` actually *is* the correct solution. (Although suffering readability.)

More reading here (not primarily about TypeScript, but the principles stand):

https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

https://ponyfoo.com/articles/binding-methods-to-class-instance-objects

Answer (score 8):

See page 72 of the typescript language specification 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf?raw=true

### Arrow Function Expressions

In the example

```
class Messenger {
 message = "Hello World";
 start() {
 setTimeout(() => alert(this.message), 3000);
 }
};
var messenger = new Messenger();
messenger.start();
```

> the use of an arrow function expression causes the callback to have
>   the same this as the surrounding  ‘start’ method. Writing the callback
>   as a standard function expression it becomes necessary to manually 
>   arrange access to the surrounding this, for example by copying it into
>   a local variable:

This is the actual generated Javascript:

```
class Messenger {
 message = "Hello World";
 start() {
 var _this = this;
 setTimeout(function() { alert(_this.message); }, 3000);
 }
};
```

Comment: Link is broken unfortunately

Comment: @JimmyKane I updated the link. Strangely this doc is over a year old and still referenced by their homepage but the important content I included in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem arises when you pass a function as a callback. By the time the callback has executed the value of "this" could have changed to the Window, the control invoking the callback, or something else.

Make sure you always use a lambda expression at the point you pass a reference to the function to be called back.  For example

```
public addFile(file) {
  this.files.push(file);
}
//Not like this
someObject.doSomething(addFile);
//but instead, like this
someObject.doSomething( (file) => addFile(file) );
```

This compiles to something like

```
this.addFile(file) {
  this.files.push(file);
}
var _this = this;
someObject.doSomething(_this.addFile);
```

Because the addFile function is being called on a specific object reference (_this) it does not use the "this" of the invoker but instead the value of _this.

Comment: When you say what it compiles to, which one are you showing?  (The arrow instance or the the one that just passes the method object?)

Comment: The lambda. Just create a TS with that code and take a look at what it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the this keyword always has a reference to the object that called the function.

In Javascript, since functions are just variables, you can pass them around.

Example:

```
var x = {
   localvar: 5, 
   test: function(){
      alert(this.localvar);
   }
};

x.test() // outputs 5

var y;
y.somemethod = x.test; // assign the function test from x to the 'property' somemethod on y
y.test();              // outputs undefined, this now points to y and y has no localvar

y.localvar = "super dooper string";
y.test();              // outputs super dooper string
```

When you do the following with jQuery:

```
$.proxy(this.update, this);
```

What you are doing is overriding that context. Behind the scenes jQuery will guive you this:

```
$.proxy = function(fnc, scope){
  return function(){
     return fnc.apply(scope);  // apply is a method on a function that calls that function with a given this value
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it this way?
Declare a global variable of type "myClass" and initialise it in the constructor of the class:

```
var _self: myClass;

class myClass {
    classScopeVar: string = "hello";

    constructor() {
        _self = this;
    }

    alerter() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(_self.classScopeVar)
        }, 500);
    }
}

var classInstance = new myClass();
classInstance.alerter();
```

Note: It is important NOT to use "self" as it as a special meaning already.

Comment: Big Problem: all instances of the class have the same _self so it doesn't work.