# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: typescript

```
    interface IMySocks {
        start(): void;
    }

    declare var $;

    class MySocks implements IMySocks {

        private address: string;
        private protocols = [];
        private mySock: WebSocket;
start() {
        this.mySock = new WebSocket(this.address, this.protocols);
        this.mySock.onclose = this.onclose;
        this.mySock.onopen = this.onopen;
        this.mySock.onerror = this.onerror;
        this.mySock.onmessage = this.onmessage;
    }

private onopen(): void {
        this.sendIt();
        console.debug("OPEN");
    }

private sendIt() {
.....}
```

var my: IMySocks = new MySocks();
my.start();

So such class comes to Error in the subject. Intellisense and compilation found no error in typescript file. I am using VS2012 Ultimate update 2 with typescript 1.0.  What wrong ?

Trhe problem raises when I call this.sendIt();

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157839/typescript-this-inside-a-class-method or any other question tagged with `typescript` and `this`

Comment: doesn't work. Anyway the code using ()=> is rather ugly. Why TS doesn't make a error message on compilation stage ? Because TS guess this is right code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike some other programming languages like C# which would preserve the `this` context to be what you wanted automatically, the `this` context in JavaScript is a bit different. For more details, you might read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Instead of creating a closure to capture `this`, uou might also consider a more typical JavaScript approach using `bind` available in ES5 ([Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) / [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)):

```
this.mySock.onclose = this.onclose.bind(this);
```

`bind` returns a function that is bound to the provided `this` context (or any context you'd like). That function (`onclose`) will be called at run time with the proper context set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in that case does not point to your instance of `MySocks` but to the instance of `WebSocket`.

If you want the `this` reference to work you could do the following

```
this.mySock.onopen = () => { this.onopen(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lambda if you plan to pass a function around. Either what Dennis recommends or :

```
private onopen =  () => {
        this.sendIt();
        console.debug("OPEN");
    }
```

For the reason see : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1 It is because the calling context is lost if you simply pass a member function without using a lambda (and let someone else call it).