# Typescript callback is null from paste event

Tags: javascript, callback, typescript, this

```
interface myCallbackType { (dataType: string): void }

class PasteUtilities {

    public myCallback: myCallbackType;   

    public pasteHandler(e) {
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            console.log('file received');
            this.myCallback(items[i].type);
        }
    }

    public RegisterEvent() {
        window.addEventListener("paste", this.pasteHandler);
    }    
}

var utils = new PasteUtilities();    
utils.myCallback = function (dataType: string) {
    console.log('Filetype: ' + dataType);
}
utils.RegisterEvent();
utils.myCallback('test type'); //test to make sure it's wired up right
```

The intention of this code is to have some function run when a file is pasted into the browser. The function to run is stored in `myCallback`.

My test sequence is that I access the page and paste a single file. Here's my expected output when pasting a png file.

```
Filetype: test type
file received
Filetype: image/png
```

Here's my actual output:

```
Filetype: test type
file received
Uncaught TypeError: this.myCallback is not a function
```

I guess it's something about the context of the browser's paste event is not the same, so `myCallback` is null. How can I correct this?

I have looked at the issue in the [possible duplicate mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157839/typescript-this-inside-a-class-method) and I don't see how it's relevant to what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've lost the `this` context because you have used a class method (`this.pasteHandler`) from the prototype in a place where it's not invoked (in `RegisterEvent`).

You need to make either this edit:

```
    public RegisterEvent() {
        // Use arrow function here
        window.addEventListener("paste", e => this.pasteHandler(e));
    }
```

Or this edit:

```
// Use arrow function here
public pasteHandler = (e) => {
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log('file received');
        this.myCallback(items[i].type);
    }
}
```

See also [TypeScript "this" scoping issue when called in jquery callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback)

Comment: Yes, it does clarify. I find this syntax confusing. I had seen a video where Anders demonstrates some of this issues surround `this` but I guess I didn't fully understand the ramifications.