# Javascript object this is alway window

Tags: javascript

I've asked this in the past but still not understanding why my this is always window and not the calling object.

on the page there is button control:

```
<input type="button" value="Press Me" id="buttonPressMe" @click="pressMeClicked" />
```

This is the component and under methods is where I have functions:

[image]

[image]

pressMeClicked() is the function that gets called:

```
pressMeClicked: () => {
    console.log(this.el)
    var dd = this;
    console.log('pressMeClicked');
}
```

The problem is **this** is not the component object in the pressMeClicked() function.  It's always the **window** object.  The code below shows how I add an event listener to the element.  And either of the two options I used does call the pressMeClicked function. The only problem is that this is not the component obj but window:

```
const funcBind = function(obj, method, args = []){
    return function(){
        return method.apply(obj, args);
    }
}

const funcProcess = (component, elements) => {

    const fn = component.methods['pressMeClicked'];
    const methodCall = funcBind(component, fn);
    const elem = component.selector('#buttonPressMe');

    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Tried this
        fn.bind(component)()
        // Tried this also
        methodCall();
    }       
}
```

When I step into the function methodCall(), obj is the component.

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: You can't rebind an arrow function context. It's bound to whatever context it was defined in, that's kind of the idea. Try with `pressMeClicked: function(){ console.log( this) }`.

Comment: I have tried it using elem.addEventListener('click', function(){} also and I get the same result

Comment: Because neither `fn.bind` nor `funcBind( component, fn)` will work when `fn` is an arrow function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript "this" inside a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157839/typescript-this-inside-a-class-method)

Comment: Take a look at [**'this' in TypeScript**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript).

Comment: Thanks pawel, I get it now.  Learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pressMeClicked` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is a non-bound function. Because of that, `this` will always refer to the value of `this` inside the *lexical scope* of its containing function. To fix this change the arrow function definition to a regular function (method):

```
// Instead of:
pressMeClicked: () => {
    // ...
}

// Do this:
pressMeClicked() {
    // ...
}

// or:
pressMeClicked: function() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: OMG, are you kidding? Thank you so much.  That fixed the issue.

Comment: Haha, one of those days ;) Glad to help you out.