# how do I get a reference to the instance of a class that I am in if I am in an object within another object within that class?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building an `angular` application and I have a class that I'm defining within another ts file. I'm trying to get a property that is defined by the `constructor` but I'm within an `object` that is in another `object`. Normally I would use the "this" keyword but it is referring to the `object` I am in and not the parent class.

here is the use of the class:

```
var devList = new DateList(dates)
```

here is a simplified version of the DateList class:

```
export class DateList {
  date
  constructor(input){
    this.date = input
  }

  devs = {
    bluegreen: {
      dates: this.date.bluegreen //<-----------I believe "this" in this 
                                 //            case refers to bluegreen, 
                                 //            how do I get it to refer
                                 //            to this instance of the 
                                 //            DateList class?
    }
  }

}
```

**EDIT**
I'm a beginner to programing so I don't understand what a function has to do with an object, inside of another object. can anyone explain how to fix the issue, and how the issue applies to functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript "this" inside a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157839/typescript-this-inside-a-class-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting class attributes happens before the constructor, so this.date is undefined when you are declaring the class attribute 'devs'.  Move setting 'devs' inside the constructor and it will work:

```
export class DateList {

  private date: any;
  public devs: Object;

  constructor(input: Object){
    this.date = input

    this.devs = {
      bluegreen: {
        dates: this.date.bluegreen
      }
    }
  }
}

let dateList: DateList = new DateList({
  bluegreen: 'bluegreen_val'
});

console.log(dateList.devs);
```